# How to pass dynamic array in UI Kitten v5 select?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-ui-kitten

How to pass dynamic data in select?

```
const array=['a','b','c','d'] 
 <Select data={array} 
  selectedIndex={selectedIndex}   
  onSelect={index => setSelectedIndex(index)}> 
   </Select>
```

Whenever i use

```
<SelectItem title='Option 1'/> 
<SelectItem title='Option 2'/> 
<SelectItem title='Option 3'/>
```

it is working fine but when I am using data its not working

Comment: How do you using data as prop in SelectItem? Share code

Comment: I am using UI kitten for the very first time. I can get from their docs is `    <Layout style={styles.container} level='1'>
      <Select
        selectedIndex={selectedIndex}
        onSelect={index => setSelectedIndex(index)}>
        <SelectItem title='Option 1'/>
        <SelectItem title='Option 2'/>
        <SelectItem title='Option 3'/>
      </Select>
    </Layout>
 `

Comment: I am trying render my array in SelectItem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help

```
const array = ['a','b','c','d'];

export const SelectDisplayValueShowcase = () => {

  const renderOption = (title) => (
    <SelectItem title={title}/>
  );

  return (
    <Layout style={styles.container} level='1'>

      <Select
        style={styles.select}>
        {array.map(renderOption)}
      </Select>

    </Layout>
  );
};
```